# Absolute images contained in a dynamic div aren't dynamic

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm trying to have images that are positioned absolutely (so I can modify their position in JS), contained in a div (responsive by bootstrap), and scale based on viewer.

Currently it looks good on a full-screen browser, but as soon as I re-size the screen, the divs scale in width, but the images stay the same size.

Being new to SO, what is the preferred method of showing code--jsfiddle, code tags, or the live webpage?

**EDIT 4 - JSFiddle Update**
I updated the JSFiddle so it points to the correct images.

**EDIT 3 - JSFiddle**
I think I did this right, never used JSFiddle before.  [Here's the link](https://jsfiddle.net/wsmrumsa/5/).

**EDIT 1: -Add Code-**
My Goal: I want this to look good, and usable, on a mobile device as well as desktop/laptop. Currently it only looks nice on a maximized desktop browser window.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Matching Game</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="matching/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="matching/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="matching/css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal_instructions" data-backdrop=true>
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1>GAMEPLAY INSTRUCTIONS</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Find the face on the left game-screen that is out of place.  There will always be exactly one extra face on the left than the right. Find it, and win!</p>
                        <h2>Example:</h2>
                        <img src="img/gameBoard.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container" id="gameBoard">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="instructions">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <h3>Welcome to my Matching Game, enjoy!</h3>
                    <p>When the game starts, smiley faces will be populated on both sides of the screen.  The object is to find the object in the left side that is not in the right side.</p>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_instructions">Instructions</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="gameStart">START GAME!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-xs-12" id="playArea">
                    <div class="col-xs-6" id="leftSide" style="display: none">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var leftSideImages;
        var theBody = "";
        var numberOfFaces = 5;
        var leftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
        var rightSide = "";

        document.getElementById("gameStart").onclick = function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
//                leftSide.style.width = "500px";
            theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

            document.getElementById("gameBoard").removeChild(document.getElementById("instructions"));
            document.getElementById("leftSide").style.display = "block";

            generateFaces();
        }
        // Generate the faces on the left side first
        function generateFaces() {

            for ( i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
                var newImage = document.createElement("img");
                newImage.setAttribute("src", "img/smile.png");
                newImage.className += "img-responsive";

                var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 1;
                var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 1;

                newImage.style.top = y + "px";
                newImage.style.left = x + "px";

                leftSide.appendChild(newImage);
            }

            // Now let's clone the left panel to the right, and remove one smiley face
            leftSideImages = leftSide.cloneNode(true);
            leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
            leftSideImages.setAttribute("id", "rightSide");
            document.getElementById("playArea").appendChild(leftSideImages);
            rightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");

            // Add event handler function to the extra face
            leftSide.lastChild.style.opacity = 0.25;

            leftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
                numberOfFaces += 5;

                while (leftSide.lastChild) {
                    leftSide.removeChild(leftSide.lastChild);
                }

                while (rightSide.lastChild) {
                    rightSide.removeChild(rightSide.lastChild);
                }

                document.getElementById("playArea").removeChild(rightSide);

                generateFaces();
            }

            // Event handler to handle incorrect choices
            theBody.onclick = function gameOver(event) {

                numberOfFaces = 5;

                leftSide.lastChild.style.opacity = 1;

                // Challenge: Show the user where the correct choice is with a red highlight
                var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                newDiv.style.position = "absolute";
                newDiv.style.height = "76px";
                newDiv.style.width = "76px";
                newDiv.style.top = parseInt(leftSide.lastChild.style.top)+12+"px";
                newDiv.style.left = parseInt(leftSide.lastChild.style.left)+12+"px";
                newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75)";
                newDiv.style.borderRadius = "50px";
                leftSide.appendChild(newDiv);
                newDiv = "";

                // Remove all faces from the rightSide
                while (rightSide.lastChild) {
                    rightSide.removeChild(rightSide.lastChild);
                }

                // Dim the rightSide game screen -- 'Turn off the lights'
                rightSide.style.backgroundColor = "rgba( 180, 180, 180, .85)";
                rightSide.style.boxShadow = "inset -132px -132px 152px rgba( 0, 50, 127, 0.25), inset 132px 132px 152px rgba( 0, 50, 127, 0.25), inset -12px -12px 22px #333, inset 2px 2px 32px #333, -10px 15px 25px #000, inset 2px 2px 32px rgba( 0, 50, 127, 0.25)";
                rightSide.style.paddingTop = "13%";
                rightSide.style.textAlign = "center";
                rightSide.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
                rightSide.style.zIndex = 1000;


                // Game Over! Screen with 'Try Again' button
                leftSide.lastChild.style.border = "border: solid 1px red";
                theBody.onclick = null;
                leftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;

                rightSide.innerHTML = "<h1>Game Over!</h1>";
                rightSide.style.fontWeight = "bold";
                rightSide.style.color = "#000";
                var btn_tryAgain = document.createElement("button");
                btn_tryAgain.className = "btn btn-info gameOver";
                btn_tryAgain.textContent = "Try Again";
                rightSide.appendChild(btn_tryAgain);

                // Restart the game
                btn_tryAgain.onclick = function(event) {

                    event.stopPropagation();

                    while (leftSide.lastChild) {
                        leftSide.removeChild(leftSide.lastChild);
                    }

                    document.getElementById("playArea").removeChild(rightSide);

                    generateFaces();
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

And, finally, my CSS

```
img { position: absolute; max-width: 100%; height: auto; }

body { font-size: 2rem; }

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 20px;
    background: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    color: lightgrey;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.close:hover {
    color: black;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

#leftSide{
    height: 500px;
/*    border: solid 1px black;*/
    border-radius: 5%;
/*    margin: 10px;*/
    box-shadow: inset -132px -132px 152px rgba( 0, 100, 255, 0.25), inset 132px 132px 152px rgba( 0, 100, 255, 0.25), inset -12px -12px 22px #333, inset 2px 2px 32px #333, -10px 15px 25px #000, inset 2px 2px 32px rgba( 0, 100, 255, 0.25); 
}

#rightSide {
    height: 500px;
/*    border: solid 1px black;*/
    border-radius: 5%;
/*    margin: 10px;*/
    box-shadow: inset -132px -132px 152px rgba( 0, 100, 255, 0.25), inset 132px 132px 152px rgba( 0, 100, 255, 0.25), inset -12px -12px 22px #333, inset 2px 2px 32px #333, -10px 15px 25px #000, inset 2px 2px 32px rgba( 0, 100, 255, 0.25); 
}

.text-center { text-align: center; }

.text-left { text-align: left; }

.text-right { text-align: right; }

.text-justify { text-align: justify; }

#startGame p {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: blue;
    font-family: serif, cursive;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#startGame img {
    margin: 5px;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.modal-header h1 {
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.modal-body img {
    position: inherit;
}
```

**EDIT 2**
The most common advice was for me to change the position to absolute. After doing so, the faces no longer appear on the "playArea" as desired. I guess I'm showing my 'green-horn' status, but is what I'm trying to do even feasible? Here is a screenshots of the [unmodified](http://tinypic.com/r/166ziv/9) (position: absolute) screens. The Modified (position: relative) can be seen it the JSFiddle below. Since I can only have 2 active links, I had to remove the img link to the modified screen.

**END EDIT**

Comment: You should show your code in your post and it would be helpful to have a jsfiddle. You should not show a live webpage as these links can break over time making the post useless for others in the future. Post up your code so car and we can try to help.

Comment: Updated the post to show the code involved, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hi Michael, can you please upload the concept to a JSFiddle please. It's very difficult to figure out what's going on based on that code alone.

Comment: You could try doing the absolute positioning using percentages instead of a fixed size. You could also make it so that when you resize the browser, it regenerates the positions.

Comment: Post Updated to add a JSFiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Use position:relative instead of position:absolute

Comment: Updated my post with the results of updating the position to absolute.  Thank you for your feedback, but I'm still not able to achieve the results I'm looking for.